# Service broker stuck infinitely looping using outdated activation stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, cache

I was debugging and stuck a bunch of log statements into my activation procedure including a statement that logs the value of @@ROWCOUNT that is used in this manner:

```
INSERT INTO ###Debug(SomeMessage, SomeData)
VALUES ('row count', @@ROWCOUNT)

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    BREAK
END
```

However, I made a critical mistake here because saving the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` in this manner makes it always return 1 on the next call, so the rollback statement never runs.

I modified my activation stored procedure to set `@@ROWCOUNT` in a variable to fix my problem, but now I keep seeing an error show up every 5 seconds (waitfor receive with timeout of 5 seconds) in SQL Server Profiler from the **old version** of the stored procedure.

[image]

Apparently SQL Server has decided to continue using the old stored procedure even though I altered it!

I have never seen this behavior before of SQL Server caching code, and a google search for "Service broker caching stored procedures" doesn't return anything relevant.

I even tried

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
DROP PROCEDURE SB_..._Consume
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SB_..._Consume ...
```

How do I escape the infinite loop of failed conversation handling?

P.S. The initiating `BEGIN DIALOG` statement included `LIFETIME = 600` but it has been stuck for nearly an hour now, well beyond the 10 minute timeout I gave it!

Using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise (test database is in 2008R2 compatibility mode).

**Edit**: Using SSDT to publish the updated database from Visual Studio fixed it. There must be a better way though.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you stop and start SB? This might help. STOP/START the endpoint, or the queue. If this doesn't work, DROP/CREATE the service again referring to the handler stored proc.

Comment: I'm guessing that is what fixed it.